# Put data in next blank row, selecting wrong column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sure it's simple but i'm trying to get it to paste the data in Column U first blank cell. It's currently pasting in Column A starting from cell A28.

```
function Update() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("U:U").getValues();
  var maxIndex = values.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
  return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1));
  sheet.getRange('L28:S').copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values to the first blank of the column "U" as the destination range.
- The source range is `L28:S`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the destination range is `sheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1)`. By this, the values are copied to the column "A". I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- In your situation, I thought that `getNextDataCell` might be able to be used.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function Update() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // I modified below script.
  var range = sheet.getRange("U1:U" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var temp = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
  var destRange = temp.getRow() == sheet.getMaxRows() && sheet.getRange("U1").isBlank() ? sheet.getRange("U1") : temp.offset(1, 0);
  // destRange.activate();  // When you use this line, the start of copy is activated.
  sheet.getRange('L28:S').copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I've given this a try but i'm getting the following error: "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

Comment: @Curtis Humphreys Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.